# How to rearrange the priorities of the records using Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have a requirement to auto update priorities based on the input from the user.
On Object Requests__c I have 2 fields Priority__c(Number) and Board__c (Picklist values A, B, C and D).
Suppose if I have 10 Requests__c records with priorities, when the priority changes the other records should be rearranged in the sequence, if the priority changes from 7 to 3, the rest of them should be moved down in the sequence order.

I tried below logic, but the sequencing not updating as expected. Can someone suggest any idea on how to achieve it?

Apex trigger will call the below method on after insert and after update.

```
public void updatePriority(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
        Map<Id, Request__c> newRecords = (Map<Id, Request__c>) newItems;
        Map<Id, Request__c> oldRecords = (Map<Id, Request__c>) oldItems;
        Map<Decimal,Request__c> reqMap = new Map<Decimal,Request__c>();
        Map<Id,Integer> originalPriorities = new Map<Id,Integer>();
        map<id,Request__c> requestListMap = new map<id,Request__c>();
        Set<String> board = new Set<String>();
        List<Request__c> updatedRequests = new List<Request__c>();
        
        for (Request__c eachRequest : (List<Request__c>) newRecords.values()) {
            Request__c oldRequest = (Request__c) oldRecords.get(eachRequest.Id);
            Integer reqPriority = integer.valueOf(oldRecords.get(eachRequest.Id).Priority__c);
            if(eachRequest.Priority__c != null && eachRequest.Priority__c != oldRequest.Priority__c){
               
                board.add(eachRequest.Board__c);
            }  
        }
        List<Request__c> allRequests = [select id,Priority__c,Board__c from Request__c where id not in: oldRecords.keyset() and Board__c IN: board];
        for(Request__c oldRequest: oldRecords.values() ){
            for(Request__c sRequest: allRequests){
                
                if(sRequest.Board__c == oldRequest.Board__c){
                    if(sRequest.Priority__c > oldRequest.Priority__c){ 
                        sRequest.Priority__c -=  1;
                        updatedRequests.add(sRequest);
                    }
                    else if(sRequest.Priority__c < oldRequest.Priority__c){
                        sRequest.Priority__c +=  1;
                        updatedRequests.add(sRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        requestListMap.putall(updatedRequests);
       if (!requestListMap.isEmpty()){
            update requestListMap.values();
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to move the requests one priority at a time (-1 and +1), but this assumes that all of your priorities are already correct to begin with. What happens if, for example, a record is deleted? What about setting a Priority to null? What happens if two records end up with the same priority? What about gaps in priority? What if someone provides a fractional priority?

I've made some assumptions about the desired outcomes to come up with this code. The nice part is, no matter what your data looks like initially, after the trigger runs, your records will always be ordered in priority from 1 to *n*, where *n* is the number of requests for a given board. We order by Last Modified Date descending for ties, on the assumption that the most recently modified version has the correct priority in case of a tie.

```
static Boolean isRecursive = false;
public void updatePriority(Request__c[] newRequests) {
  // We're already handling reordering.
  if(isRecursive) {
    return;
  }
  Map<Id, List<Request__c>> requestsByBoard = new Map<Id, List<Request__c>>();
  Request__c[] updatedRequests = new Request__c[0];
  // Create a map of requests by board
  for(Request__c request: newRequests) {
    requestsByBoard.put(request.Board__c, new Request__c[0]);
  }
  // Get requests in the desired order
  for(Request__c request: [
    SELECT Priority__c, Board__c 
    FROM Request__c 
    WHERE Board__c = :requestsByBoard.keySet()
    ORDER BY Priority__c ASC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC
  ]) {
    requestsByBoard.get(request.Board__c).add(request);
  }
  // For each board...
  for(Id boardId: requestsByBoard.keySet()) {
    List<Request__c> requestsForBoard = requestsByBoard.get(boardId);
    // Check if the priority has changed for any requests.
    for(Integer index = 0; index < requestsForBoard.size(); index++) {
      Request__c indexRequest = requestsForBoard[index];
      if(indexRequest.Priority__c != index + 1) {
        indexRequest.Priority__c = index + 1;
        updatedRequests.add(indexRequest);
      }
    }
  }
  // Technically, this recursion is self-limited, but this is more efficient.
  isRecursive = true;
  update updatedRequests;
  isRecursive = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, the logic is working if I move the priority to higher numbers. But in some cases it is not allowing  users to update the priority to the number they would like to, it is automatically updating sequentially.   For example if I want to move priority from 3 to 4, the logic is still updating back the record as 3 instead of 4.